# what does the window pop before the pages even loads or the tap happens? JQUERY MOBILE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The "Call 2062710041" pops up before the pages loads all the way and the the button isnt event touched. Whats wrong with the code?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2      /jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> <script>
        $('#phone').on( 'tap',"#phone",goto());{
         function goto(event){
        window.location = 'tel:2062710041'}};
    </script>

</head>    
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" >
      <div class="leftstyle">  <img src="message.gif" width="40" height="39"></div>
        <div class="rightstyle"> <img src="call.gif" id="phone" width="40" height="39">   </div>
 <div class="center">    <img src="LOGO.png" width="209" height="210" >  </div>
```

Comment: First `goto` is reserved keyword. Rename that function goto() to any other name

Answer (score 2):

Using this method below will allow you to wait until the page is loaded to perform anything inside of it. This is jQuery's ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* your code. */ });
```

Same process outside of jQuery.

```
document.onload = function(){ /* your code. */ };
```

Comment: $document.ready() isn't quite the same as document.load though. $document.ready kicks in as soon as the DOM (HTML of the page) is ready, and doesn't make you wait for assets to load.

Comment: Not exactly 100% identical but honestly I'd prefer jQuery's ready function over document.onload = function() { }; any day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's ready() function to bind the tap on full load. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {/*your code*/})
```

You also have a couple of extra {} brackets

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#phone').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.handled !== true)
    {
        location.href = 'tel:2062710041';
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
 });`
```

Comment: Answers should never only include code. Tell what you did, so that if someone with a similar, but not quite the same, problem would visit this question, your answer could be useful to them.